# Como hacer para que una funcion nos permita ingresar tantos argumentos como queramos

Tags: javascript, string, funciones, parametros

mi pregunta es simple, como hacer para que una función nos permita ingresar tantos strings como queramos para después concatenar los a todos. Algo así seria la invocación:

```
concatenar('Hola', ' ', 'como', ' ', 'están');
```

Lo que tengo hecho:

```
function concatenar([array]){
var res = array.join('');
return res;
};
```

Que claramente no funciona por que se tendría que pasar como array desde la invocación, el tema es que tiene que ser con strings, no con un array

Answer (score 0):

Se llaman [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) y nos permiten representar un número indefinido de argumentos como un arreglo.

Para tu caso específico, podrías tener algo así:

```
function concatenar(...cadenas){
   return cadenas.reduce((previous, current) => {
      return previous+ " " + current;
        });
  }

console.log(concatenar("hola","mundo"));
// hola mundo
```

Podrás escribir cuantos parámetros desees.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías definir la función sin argumentos y usar el [objeto arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments) para obtenerlos, convertir en array con [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values) y concatenar con el método [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join)

```js
function concatenar() {
  return Object.values(arguments).join(' ') || '';
}

console.log(concatenar('Hola', 'cómo', 'están'));
```